# Wildfly doesn't recognize jboss deployment structure file

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-8

I'm trying to configure Wildfly to use per deployment logging and jackson as provider for json on resteasy but looks like the AS doesn't recognize the file "jboss-deployment-structure.xml".

I wanna log the hibernate sql, i already put "`<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>`" in persistence.xml.

And for Jackson, i use the following method:

```
    @GET
    @Path("/resumodia")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes("*/*")
    @GZIP
    public Response resumoHorariosDoDia() {
        try {
            final ResumoHorariosUsuarioDoDia resumoHorariosDoDia = geradorDeResumoHorarios.getResumoHorariosDoDia(new Date());

            return Response.status(OK).entity(resumoHorariosDoDia).build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Response.status(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity("Erro ao processar a requisição: " + e.getMessage()).build();
        }
    }
```

The method works, but it ignores the json annotation i use on the object i return, like `@JsonIgnore`

The file is this one:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="logging" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jettison-provider"/>
        </exclusions>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" services="import"/>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

I put the file inside WEB-INF but it keeps using the wildfly logging and ignoring my log4j.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM
        "http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/xml/doc-files/log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/"
                     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                     xsi:schemaLocation="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/
http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/ ">

    <appender name="stdout" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %5p [%-20c{1}] %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <category name="br.com.caelum">
        <priority value="INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="stdout"/>
    </category>

    <category name="org.hibernate">
        <priority value="INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="stdout"/>
    </category>

    <category name="org.hibernate.SQL">
        <priority value="DEBUG"/>
        <appender-ref ref="stdout"/>
    </category>

    <category name="org.jboss">
        <priority value="INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="stdout"/>
    </category>

    <category name="org.razor.cponto">
        <priority value="INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="stdout"/>
    </category>

</log4j:configuration>
```

I'm using VRaptor 4

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to use per deployment logging, simply package your log4j.xml file with your deployment, there should be no need to mess about with deployment descriptors. What I do notice however is that your log4j config is trying to append to stdout rather than to an actual log file that is specific to this specific deployment, so it might well be actually using your new config, but then simply being merged into the main jboss logging due to lack of suitable appender

Comment: Looks like you are right, when i create an appender for file, the file gets created by log4j, but the logs just doesn't go to the file neither the console.

Comment: Can you post a small scale example project as a test?

Comment: Actually, looks like your log4j config defines an appender, but does not actually attach it to anything

Comment: What do you mean? isn't the "<appender-ref ref="stdout"/>" attaching it to the category?

Comment: <root>
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="stdout" />
 </root>

Comment: Tryied with no success. I'm gonna try to make a small project so you can try.

Comment: You can't use stdout when inside jboss, you need to use something like a file appender

Comment: hmmmm i thought it's possible, because i was using with log4j2 in another project