# Wildfly webapp does not log

Tags: logging, wildfly-8

I am new to wildlfy (comming from tomcat) and all my apps are using log4j. For some reason my webapps do not log anythig.

I have tried to use WEB-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logging" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logging.jul-to-slf4j-stub" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logmanager" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logmanager.log4j" />
            <module name="org.slf4j" />
            <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

But no luck. This is my rather simple log4j.properties located in classes/ and symliked to WEB-INF/

```
log4j.rootLogger=TRACE, stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%t %-5p %c{2} - %m%n
log4j.logger.org.reflections=OFF
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/28683255/967088

Comment: in fact for some reason you are just not able to log to stdout ...